# Youtube API Player on Android

Tags: android, api, youtube

Is there anyway to put an image over the youtube player or hide the video (playing in the background)? When i tried to put an image over the player, video started but it stops 1-2 sec later.

Answer (score 1):

They explicitly prevent you from doing this.

This was already discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087147/is-it-possible-to-overlay-some-views-on-youtube-android-player)

That being said, you can create the player chromeless and create your own chrome whose bounds don't overlap the player. Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but that could help. You would just need to tie your chrome controls into the player using the player API.